Drains inside basement along with french drain
I have a French drain so when the power goes out we get a flooded basement. Just curious why there was not a drain inside there is one right outside the door, doesn’t help when the basement is flooded. I remember my grandparents had a drain inside. Is there a logical reason they no longer have inside drains.

Does the "drain right outside the door" continue to take water away when the power is out, or does it flood? If it still works, you can drill a hole in the wall to connect it to the inside, probably.

Note that a French Drain does not imply something that requires power (a pump) to operate.
Generally the reason that a house will not have a drain leading from the basement to a lower place where water can run by gravity alone is due to either terrain (there is no "lower place" within a reasonable distance yet they put in a basement anyway) or cost-cutting (cheaper for the developer to put in a sump pit and pump than to bother to dig the trench to a place that gravity-drains, and they were not planning to live in the houses they built anyway.)
Few if any buyers are picky enough to pay more for a gravity drain, and many houses are built on flat land.
If your system is such that you have flooding when the power goes out, you either need to use and finish the basement in such a way that it's no big deal (hard tile or painted concrete, nothing that is ruined if it gets wet below flood level) or you need to arrange for a backup means of pumping when the power goes out.
